# .Net 6 Web Api docker port forwarding issue

Tags: docker, .net-6.0

I have an empty .NET 6 web api solution with swagger installed. I have generated a docker file from Visual Studio which looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Api.Permissions/Api.Permissions.csproj", "Api.Permissions/"]
COPY ["Api.Permissions.Models/Api.Permissions.Models.csproj", "Api.Permissions.Models/"]
COPY ["Api.Permissions.Services/Api.Permissions.Services.csproj", "Api.Permissions.Services/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Api.Permissions/Api.Permissions.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api.Permissions"
RUN dotnet build "Api.Permissions.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.Permissions.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.Permissions.dll"]
```

I have created a docker image and pushed to my docker hub account.

I have then run this command to pull and run the image locally:

```
docker container run -d --name mynewapi -p 8000:443 myusername/myreponame:mycontainername
```

However when I browse to http://localhost:433/swagger/index.html I get:

> This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.

I have also tried to make a GET request using postman to the sample endpoint but i just get the same error.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run the container, you map port 443 in the container to port 8000 on the host. So you need to access it using port 8000.

Since you map port 443 which is the https port, you should be using https. So your URL should be ​`https://localhost:8000/swagger/index.html`

But that still isn't enough. By default Swagger is only available when your solution is running in Development mode. You control that using the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` which needs to be set to 'Development'. You can do that in your docker command when you run the container like this

```
docker container run -d --name mynewapi -p 8000:443 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development myusername/myreponame:mycontainername
```

or you can add it to the Dockerfile like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Api.Permissions/Api.Permissions.csproj", "Api.Permissions/"]
COPY ["Api.Permissions.Models/Api.Permissions.Models.csproj", "Api.Permissions.Models/"]
COPY ["Api.Permissions.Services/Api.Permissions.Services.csproj", "Api.Permissions.Services/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Api.Permissions/Api.Permissions.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api.Permissions"
RUN dotnet build "Api.Permissions.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.Permissions.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.Permissions.dll"]
```